# Will a post-subsidy block with no transactions include a coinbase transaction?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, reward-schedule

If a block:

- Is after the last halving, so there is no subsidy
- Includes no non-coinbase transactions, so there are no fees

Must it include a coinbase transaction? If so, will it simply have no outputs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Bitcoin block is required to have a coinbase transaction, regardless of fees or subsidy.

Additionally, every transaction (including the coinbase), must have at least one output (possibly 0-valued), and at least one input (in the case of a coinbase, this isn't actually spending any actual UTXO, though).

In a block with 0 fees and 0 subsidy, this implies a coinbase transaction with only 0-value outputs.